# How to balance an avl tree with steps?

Tags: trees

I am not getting how to balance an AVL tree, I have looked for the answers online but that was not clearing my doubts.

Comment: I think this question is more for computer science.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you explain what an AVL tree is?